# app has stopped on button click performing OCR on device but working fine in emulator

Tags: android

I have this code on button click its working just fine in android emulator nexus 5 but when I installed it in android phone and click the scanned button I get the error Unfortunately app has stopped.

can anyone help me??

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String imgPath = extras.getString("picPath");
Bitmap bmp = decodeBitmapFile(imgPath, 1200, 1500);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scanText();
        }
    });

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFile(String filePath,int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);}
```

code in performing OCR

```
public void scanText(){
        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imgPath);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);
            int rotate = 0;
            switch (exifOrientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
            }
            if (rotate != 0) {
                // Getting width & height of the given image.
                int w = bmp.getWidth();
                int h = bmp.getHeight();
                // Setting pre rotate
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.preRotate(rotate);
                // Rotating Bitmap
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
            }
            bmp = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");
        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
        baseApi.setImage(bmp);
        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
        baseApi.end();
        Log.v(TAG, "Scanned TEXT: " + recognizedText);
        if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng")) {
            recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "");
        }
        recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();
        if (recognizedText.length() != 0) {
            Intent x = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
            x.putExtra("txtScan", recognizedText);
            x.putExtra("pic", imgPath);
            startActivity(x);
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Error while extracting text..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
}
```

This is the error in LOGCAT

```
09-08 11:36:36.424    7588-7588/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.scanme.scanme, PID: 7588
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "png_set_longjmp_fn" referenced by "liblept.so"...
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
        at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:44)
        at com.scanme.scanme.Main2Activity.scanText(Main2Activity.java:131)
        at com.scanme.scanme.Main2Activity$2.onClick(Main2Activity.java:94)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4493)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18586)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post your logcat too

Comment: what are the characteristics (android os version, memory, screen size, image size - the one you want to scan) of the version running on the emulator ?

Comment: os version is lollipop, image size is 300dpi

Comment: I got it solve by downloading latest version of tess-two and build it again... thank you for the answer...this thread is close now.